# jq: convert all fields of a JSON object into CSV

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have this JSON object

```json
{
  "a": 68370432,
  "b": 50462720,
  "c": 53608448,
  "d": 245039104
}
```

where a, b, c, d are arbitrary field names, with plain values.

How to convert it into a CSV like this using jq ?

```
a,68370432
b,50462720
c,53608448
d,245039104
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`to_entries`** in order to be able to derive key-value pairs, then combine the pieces by using **`join`** such as

```
jq -r '. | to_entries[] | [ .key, .value ] | join(",")'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Mdqapu9fyxn)</kbd>

or use without individually paraphraising *key* and *value* such as

```
jq -r '. | to_entries[] | [ .[] ] | join(",")'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9DHdxx1lSUi)</kbd>

or if the quotes should be kept within the results, then use

```
jq -r '. | to_entries[] | [ .[] ] | @csv'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4cr4-UD2fk_L)</kbd>